# Erro ao fazer deploy no servidor glassfish

Tags: java, jsf, deploy, glassfish, jboss-weld

Projeto não rada no servidor apos deploy.  glassfish 4.1

Projeto cdi, jsf,primefaces,jpa

> Erro de sistema: WELD-000335: Context is already active java.lang.IllegalStateException: WELD-000335: Context is already active at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractConversationContext.activate(AbstractConversationContext.java:233) at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.activateConversations(WeldPhaseListener.java:108) at org.jboss.weld.jsf.WeldPhaseListener.beforePhase(WeldPhaseListener.java:85) at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:228) at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99) at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121) at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:186) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673) at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459) at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167) at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201) at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175) at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133) at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112) at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561) at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112) at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117) at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56) at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137) at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565) at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.10.Final</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: O weld que você utiliza é do glassfish certo? provided? tem algum PhaseListener na aplicação executando algum procedimento no startup?

Comment: Dilnei, não sei dizer. Não sabia que existe uma versão para o glassfish. Estou usando essa dependência:
'  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.10.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>''

Comment: É que assim brother, o servidor é javaEE full então ele implementa uma versão da spec JavaEE que é JavaEE 7, esses servidores são diferentes dos servlets container, eles ja tem o CDI nativo, faz assim: remove esta dependência e declara a API do CDI, assim:
    

```<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
 <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
 <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>```

Comment: Obrigado Dilnei! vou fazer isso. Posto o resultado

Comment: Dilnei, deu certo.Mais uma vez muito obrigado!!

Comment: De nada Sidnei, parabéns por ter conseguido, abração.

Comment: @DilneiCunha é legal que inclua uma resposta à pergunta, o OP pode aceitá-la, ajudando outros que possam ter o mesmo problema :)

Comment: Ok @Bruno César, adicionado como resposta, quando não há uma resposta o post seria deletado? tem alguma doc sobre o uso do markdown aqui nos comentários? pois muitos comandos não funcionam, outro dia também tentei uma edição pós 5 min. e não foi possível, achei ruim esta parte, no geral gostei muito deste fórum, eu venho lá do GUJ, mas confesso que vocês estão anos luz a frente deles, gosto da seriedade do stack, das respostas que muitas veses são bem científicas e sem aquele monte de discução inútil que não possui embasamento técnico algum, de qualquer forma, Parabéns a todos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando utilizamos servidores javaEE full não precisamos declarar de forma explicita a lib do weld(compile), pois o servidor já implementa uma das versões do JavaEE, esses servidores são diferentes dos servlets container, eles já possuem o CDI nativo, então a solução é:

Remova esta dependência:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId> 
    <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId> 
    <version>1.1.10.Final</version> 
    <scope>compile</scope> 
</dependency>
```

e adicione a API do CDI como provided, ex:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId> 
    <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId> 
    <scope>provided</scope> 
</dependency>
```